# In a hash tree, are non-leaf nodes direct hashes of data, or are they hashes of sub-hashes?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtree

I am looking on [the wikipedia article for hash trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tree), and I am slightly confused by their diagram.

A leaf node obviously contains the hash of the underlying data.

Are leaf nodes in hash trees different than any non-leaf node?  Do non-leaf nodes contain hashes of data, or *hashes of hashes*?

Given this diagram:

[image: Hash tree diagram]

Which of these is `Hash 1` a hash of?

1. `Hash 1-0` + `Hash 1-1`
2. `Data block 002` + `Data block 003`

Or are hash trees fundamentally different depending on the application (rsync, P2P networks, Git, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what wiki article says:

> Nodes further up in the tree are the hashes of their respective
>   children. For example, in the picture hash 0 is the result of hashing
>   hash 0-0 and then hash 0-1. That is, `hash 0 = hash( hash 0-0 || hash
>   0-1 )` where || denotes concatenation.

But I truly believe that a developer may customize the tree and algorithm, use different hash functions and so on, optimizing it for different data or speed or memory or whatever.

Comment: +1 for noticing the part of the article that I missed.  I'd like to figure out how it is most commonly implemented, and that gives me a push in the right direction.  I don't know much about the choices of hash algorithms, and the sizes of their output hash data, but I have a feeling that what the article describes will generally iterate over less data, so will have better perf.  I'm going to hold out for a more authoritative answer, mentioning specific math, perf, and/or the specific choices made by popular software, but I'll come back to this answer if no one else pipes up :)